# How to split chunks when authoring libraries with webpack 4?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, publish

I'm trying to publish a custom react component to a private repository.

I use `react-loadable` to load a subcomponent on demand. When running locally, everything works fine. The index.js file correctly makes a request to the chunk.js file when needed. However, when published and used from another project, the component hits a 404 error when trying to request the subcomponent chunk. 
How am i supposed to split chunks and load them on demand when authoring a library? Is this even possible or am i thinking about it the wrong way?

Here's my webpack.config.js in case it's a simple matter of configuration:

```
module.exports = () => ({
    context: __dirname,
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: "index.js",
        library: "reactcombobox",
        libraryTarget: "umd",
        publicPath: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
        umdNamedDefine: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ options: { context: __dirname}}),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin([path.join(__dirname, './dist')], {verbose: true, allowExternal: true})
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            ['@babel/preset-env', {
                                "targets": {
                                    "browsers": ["last 4 Chrome versions"]
                                }
                            }],
                            '@babel/preset-react'
                        ],
                        plugins: [
                            '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx',
                            '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
                            '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader","css-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        react: {
            root: 'React',
            commonjs2: 'react',
            commonjs: 'react',
            amd: 'react',
        },
        'react-dom': {
            root: 'ReactDOM',
            commonjs2: 'react-dom',
            commonjs: 'react-dom',
            amd: 'react-dom',
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
});
```

Comment: how big is your library? depending on the size, it is just a waste of time. It is better to let the consumer of your library split code other than you doing it.

Comment: Not necessarily humongous. I didn't think about leaving code splitting to the consumer.

Comment: You should leave code splitting code-splitting for the dev, but not code splitting in a way that you would lazy load other componentes, but the dev could apply tree-shaking (that is the code splitting for libraries)

Comment: Tree shaking is the best and most recommended way for libraries

Comment: I wonder why don't you lazy load the components in your library?? I mean if you're using react then React.Lazy() is your candidate I suppose.

Comment: @atopcu are you trying to access a chunk of code from this repository, in some other repository and you're getting 404 for that asset?

Comment: @Mohit we have a similar issue - React.lazy would work for application, but not lib - the chunk would be created, but then the app that integrates it will try to load it from same domain, which means that lib developers need to publish their assets somehow to public in integrating app.

Answer (score 0):

if your component no relative please split to more file and use export {a1,a2};
do not use loadable.